# New Bitmap Changed on Copy Using Buffer

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

When I am using copyPixelsFromBuffer and copyPixelsToBuffer, the bitmap is not displaying as the same one, I have tried below code:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(a, 0, a.length);
int[] pixels = new int[bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight()];
bm.getPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0,bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bm.getRowBytes()*bm.getHeight());
bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);//I copy the pixels from Bitmap bm to the buffer

ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.array());
newbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(160, 160,Config.RGB_565);
newbm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer1);//I read pixels from the Buffer and put the pixels     to the Bitmap newbm.

imageview1.setImageBitmap(newbm);
imageview2.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Why the Bitmap bm and newbm did not display the same content?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are copying the pixels into a bitmap with `RGB_565` format, whereas the original bitmap from which you got the pixels must be in a different format.

The problem is clear from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) of `copyPixelsFromBuffer()`:

> The data in the buffer **is not changed in any way** (unlike `setPixels()`,
>   which converts from unpremultipled 32bit to whatever the bitmap's
>   native format is.

So either use the same bitmap format, or use `setPixels()` or draw the original bitmap onto the new one using a `Canvas.drawBitmap()` call.

Also use `bm.getWidth()` & `bm.getHeight()` to specify the size of the new bitmap instead of hard-coding as `160`.

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options opts = new Options();          opts.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;      bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(a, 0, a.length, opts);
The original bitmap's config is RGB565, even I do not set the config, the config is default as RGB565...

Comment: @Hexor Do the other methods described in my answer work? How different does `newbm` look compared to `bm`?

Comment: The size is not right, and the quality is very low. I found a solution myself which like this,  create a Bitmap called originBm, and called the BitmapFactory's decode method to initial the originBm(just make sure the parameter could initial the originBm right),  then I use newbm = originBm; newbm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer1). After this, the newbm could display the right thing. I don't know which reason cause this, but i thought maybe when using copyPixelsFromBuffer(), we miss something which the createBitmap() method could not give to us.